# Как правильно перенести данные?

Tags: c#, sql-server

У меня есть база данных с такой структурой, каждый раз как приходит пациент, допустим тот же самый, каждый раз приходится о нем заполнять информацию, что не очень удобно, проще сделать "карточку" пациента и добавлять в нее приемы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я переделал вот в такую структуру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице *PatientsImages* для хранения изображений используется filegroup-а.
Вопрос заключается в следующем, как мне перенести данные,из одной структуры в другую,учитывая что в первой таблице "Patients",записи повторяются,пример ниже,а во второй структуре эти повторения нужно перенести в "приемы", я не имею большого опыта в работе с БД, не могли бы пожалуйста направить?

*Id  | FullName   | DateOfBirth      | DateOfReceipt    | Menstrual*

5180 | Абдиева    | 13.05.1976       | 2014-05-13       | NULL

5642 | Абдиева    | 13.05.1976       | 2016-03-04       | NULL

5372 | Абдиева    | 13.05.1976       | 2015-03-05       | NULL

Comment: Абдиева | 13.05.1976 и  Абдиева | 04.03.1976 - это разные пациенты?

Comment: Это тот же самый пациент, я исправил

Comment: Да и хорошо бы выложить скрипты создания Вашей базы для тестирования, все до вечера

Comment: Вы решили свою проблему или Вам нужна помощь?

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. первоначальная таблица Patients по сути представляет приемы, я бы начал с переименования ее в "Приемы" и добавил бы nullable поле PatientID, указывающее на таблицу Patients. Тогда в PatientImages ничего менять не надо - она будет указывать на новую таблицу Приемы, что нам и нужно.

На этом можно было бы и остановиться и добавить в код логику: если FullName / DateOfBirth есть в таблице "Приемы", брать оттуда, иначе - из Пациентов. Но можно пойти дальше и нормализовать данные.

Т.к. в исходной схеме пациенты никак не идентифицировались, можно идентифицировать их по фамилии и дате рождения:

```
INSERT INTO Patients (PatientID, FullName, DateOfBirth) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FullName, DateOfBirth) as PatientID, FullName, DateOfBirth from Receptions
GROUP BY FullName, DateOfBirth
```

Затем нужно заполнить поле PatientID:

```
UPDATE Receptions SET Receptions.PatientID=Patients.PatientID
FROM Receptions INNER JOIN Patients WHERE Receptions.PatientID=Patients.PatientID
```

Затем убрать флаг NULLABLE с поля Receptions.PatientID.

Comment: Первый запрос выдает ошибку The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause

Comment: Добавил OVER(ORDER BY FullName, DateOfBirth). В ответе не готовое решение, а лишь общая идея. Думаю, с синтаксисом Вы сами справитесь. :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузнецов в дальнейшем могут возникнуть проблемы с *однофамильцами*

Comment: @Bald Для этого мы группируем еще и по дате рождения. Кстати не лишним будет проверить полученных пациентов, сгруппировав их только по ФИО. Если данных много, наверняка найдутся дубликаты с опечатками в дате рождения.

Comment: @SergeySlepov да я понимаю, но это не отменять возможности наличия *однофамильца*, я это больше для тс написал

Comment: В базе данных бардак, есть один и тот же человек, который приходил на прием, но с разными датами рождения, есть фамилии с ошибками ,хоть и один и тот же человек

Comment: Виноваты программисты, вовремя не добавившие нормализацию и автозаполнение. ;)